# can't acces member functions of a global object

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to make a game inspired by a youtube tutorial but a bit more complex , i had the snake created in the setup function but i moved it since i couldn't acces it's members from other functions and with it being global i can't acces it at all , how can i fix it ?
in the stuff.h header i have colio.h and iostream

```
bool gameOver;
std::array<std::array<int, 20>, 20> grid;
snake jerry(15, 9);
class object
{
protected:
    int m_x, m_y;
    object(int y, int x) :m_x(x), m_y(y) {};
public:
    const int getX() { return m_x; };
    const int getY() { return m_y; };
};


class snake:public object
{
private:
    enum direction
    {
        STOP,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        UP,
        DOWN,
    };
    direction dir;
public:
    snake(int y, int x) :object(y, x) {};
    const void moveSnake(char c)
    {

        if (c == 'a') { dir = LEFT; };
        if (c == 'd') { dir = RIGHT; };
        if (c == 's') { dir = DOWN; };
        if (c == 'w') { dir = UP; }

    };
    const void changeCoords(int y,int x) { m_x = x, m_y = y; };
};

class fruit :public object
{
private:
public:
    fruit(int y, int x) :object(y,x) {};
};


void setup()
{                   
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == 19 || i == 0 || i == 19)                                 // 0=space , 1=# , 2=snake, 3= fruit , 4= snake tail
            {                                                                       
                grid[j][i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                grid[j][i] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    grid[jerry.getY()][jerry.getX]=2;
    fruit fr(rand() % 20, rand() % 20);
    grid[fr.getY()][fr.getX()] = 3;

}
void draw()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {

            if (grid[j][i]==1)
            {
                std::cout << "#";
            }
            else if (grid[j][i]==0)
            {
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            else if (grid[j][i] == 2)
            {
            std::cout << "O";
            }
            else if (grid[j][i] == 3)
            {
                std::cout << "F";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    system("cls");
}
void input()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        jerry.moveSnake(_getch);
    }
}
void logic()
{

}

int main()
{
    setup();
    while (gameOver==false)
    {
        draw();
        input();
        logic();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we assume you got colio.h from a programmer's paradise?

Comment: Looks like you have `snake jerry(15, 9);` ahead of the definition of `snake`. Probably the source of most of your problems.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. I'll be here all week...

Comment: adding a class for Game can be useful